# integrate a function with R/ prevent integrate to evaluate the integrand vectorially

Tags: r

I want to integrate a function defined with an if statement. The problem is that the R-function "integrate" evaluates my function for several x values as if it was a vectorial one, so I recieve a warning telling that the condition was evaluated only for the first item of the vector. Consequently, my condition is not taken into account and the following program returns a division by zero error..
Is there a way to circumvent that.

```
f1 <- function(x) dnorm(x,0,1)

myInt <- function(f,lower,upper){

  f <- match.fun(f)
  integrand <- function(x) if (f(x)==0) 0 else 1/f(x)
  integrate(integrand,lower,upper)
}

a=myInt(f1,-Inf,Inf)
```

Comment: Comment made after the if(){}else{} confusion was solved. You still have more fundamental problems. 1/x as x -> 0 _should_ go to infinity. Out in the tails of dnorm I suspect  exp(-x^2) may be going to zero a lot faster than 1/x. So 1/dnorm goes to infinity a lot faster than x. Try: `curve(exp(-x^2), 0, 10); curve(1/x, 0, 10, add=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are two things you could do:

1) You could write you function different so it is vectorized:

```
integrand <- function(x) ifelse(f(x) == 0, 0, 1/f(x))
```

2) You can call "Vectorize" on it to make it vectorized

```
g = Vectorize(f)
```

(Also I think floating-point mischief might be coming into play here:

```
> f(38)
[1] 1.097221e-314
> 1/f(38)
[1] Inf
```

)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Your trick solved my issue for the if statement..
A floating-point mischief remains, that causes the function integrate to raise an error when it calculates infinite values for the integrand.. If any ideas to circumvent that, you're welcome

Comment: Thanks DWin.. Any ideas to circumvent the problem?

Comment: Thanks DWin, just saw your other comment.. I have indeed to reconsider the problem :-(

Comment: Try a lower bound on the integration & you'll see why DWin says it's bad math.

Comment: Yoy are going to nee both a lower _and_ an upper bound. 1/`dnorm()` is unbounded upward in both the -x and x directions.